# How to get the values of a tab form in ajax to another php file?

Tags: php, ajax

I have written a code in ajax to get the values of a form in a form tab in html to another php file email.php

But it is not showing the message in the alert().

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {

    $('#contact_form1').on('sendus', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'email.php',
        data: $('#contact_form1').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });

    });

  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="tabs-content">

<div tab-id="1" class="tab active">  
      <form name="contactForm1" id='contact_form1' method="post" action=''>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="name" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="email address">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telephone" placeholder="phone">
          </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Country" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Country" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="3" id="exampleInputMessage" placeholder="message" ></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 padd">
          <div id='mail_success' class='success' style="display:none;">Your message has been sent successfully.
          </div>
          <div id='mail_fail' class='error' style="display:none;"> Sorry, error occured this time sending your message.
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group col-xs-8 padd" id="recaptcha2"></div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 padd" id='submit'>
          <input type="submit" id='send_message' name="sendus" class="btn  btn-lg costom-btn" value="send">
        </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have written this code but when I am submitting the send button , it is not showing the message form was submitted.

Comment: Did you check the developer console? Are you getting any errors? Is it posting the data you expect? Are receiving expected data or errors? (Fyi, you can view network activity from dev console and then filter down to only the `xhr` which is ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were wrongly used the Javascript onclick function.

```
<script>
$(function () {

$('#send_message').on('click', function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'email.php',
    data: $('#contact_form1').serialize(),
    success: function (res) {
      alert('form was submitted'+res);
    }
  });

});

});
</script>
```

For submit button onclick only give .

Comment: ok..thank you so much..I want one more help..i want to get the values from this form in the php page email.php and display it there..how to do that ?

Comment: As usual in PHP, you would access values like $_POST["varname"] or $_GET["varname"] depending on the request type. you can access it

Comment: <?php $email = $_GET['email']; echo $email;exit;?> I have used this code but it is not displaying the values in email.php

Comment: Try To use $_POST["varname"] post method

Comment: after clicking send button..its showing the message form was submitted..but it is not going to the email.php file

Comment: See your using just javascript with alert  function only.. You didn't redirect tot hat page. If you want, just give form action="email.php". Or you just write a code functionality in email.php and it will perform.

Comment: Test your email.php whether getting value or not. In email.php put this code <?php $_POST["email"]
echo $_POST["email"]; ?>. and replace your JS by my answer above. you will get alert text as "form was submitted email(what you entered in text field)"

Comment: <form name="contactForm1" id='contact_form1' method="post" action='email.php'> i have put like this.stil it is not going to the php page email.php

Comment: Did you remove the javascript?

Comment: email.php is not working..the value passed to that php page is not displaying that value.

Comment: its not displaying the email value in the alert()

Comment: when i am clicking the send button without filling the form,its showing the alert message form was submitted

Comment: Hey now exactly what you want to do with that? please say clearly

Comment: Actually I want the function like : when I am clicking the send , it should send all the values entered in the text fields and dropdown to another php file email.php where I want to send these entered values to a email-id as a mail.

Comment: fine this link provide what you want. check here http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php

Answer (score 0):

Sou should add on `click` or `submit` events:
`$('#contact_form1').on('click', function (e) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code

```
 $(document).on('submit', '#contact_form1', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'email.php',
            data: $('#contact_form1').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('hii form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });
```

Hope this code will help