# How to display the values passing using ajax in another php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have written a code to pass values from a form using ajax but the values passed to another php page is not getting displayed there. I want to display the values passed in email.php file and send it as a mail to a email-id.

My script :

```js
$(function() {

  $('#send_message').on('click', function(e) {

    var name = $('#exampleInputName1').val();
    var email = $('#exampleInputEmail1').val();
    var tel = $('#exampleInputTelephone1').val();
    var cn = $('#exampleInputCountry1').val();
    var message = $('#exampleInputMessage1').val();

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'php/email.php',
      data: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        tel: tel,
        cn: cn,
        message: message
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert(message);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

html page:

```html
<form name="contactForm1" id='contact_form1' method="post" action='php/email.php'>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputName1" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="email address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telephone" id="exampleInputTelephone1" placeholder="phone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Country" id="exampleInputCountry1" placeholder="Country">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
      <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="3" id="exampleInputMessage1" placeholder="message"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 padd">
    <div id='mail_success' class='success' style="display:none;">Your message has been sent successfully.
    </div>
    <!-- success message -->
    <div id='mail_fail' class='error' style="display:none;">Sorry, error occured this time sending your message.
    </div>
    <!-- error message -->
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-xs-8 padd" id="recaptcha2"></div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-4 padd" id='submit'>
    <input type="submit" id='send_message' name="sendus" class="btn  btn-lg costom-btn" value="send">
  </div>
</form>
```

email.php

```
<?php
 $temp = $_POST['name'];
 echo $temp;
?>
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this ?

Comment: you also use url in action and also in ajax just use only one action , ajax or just submit only

Comment: Firstly change click to `$("#contact_form1").on("submit",function(e) {  e.preventDefault(); var name...`  then try to post without JS to see if there are PHP errors. 
@AmitChauhan why would that make a difference? With the action, the form can be submitted even when JS is turned off

Comment: So what does happen when you click the submit button?

Comment: this question already asked same form.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873533/how-to-get-the-values-of-a-tab-form-in-ajax-to-another-php-file/37873603?noredirect=1#comment63205269_37873603